# Break UICollectionView and make full screen

Tags: xcode, swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview, uisplitviewcontroller

Hey im new to xCode and Swift.

I have an UICollectionView inside an Split View controller, and i want to break free of the split view controller when i press, the cell then it should go to another viewcontroller and show an image inside an web view. The view should fill the whole screen and not just the right side of the screen.
I would like if you then hit close then i should return to the CollectionView Controller

Comment: You could use a modal controller to do that, so when you press one of the cells, it pops up taking up the full screen, then when dismissed user is taken right back to the original screen. Probably the easiest way to do this

Comment: @AdamM Thanks Adam i think your right, i have just gotten an ideer. The splitView will always be full screen on the iPhone but on the iPad the user should have the option to press a button to get the view to full screen. If you understand what im saying

Answer (score -2):

You can use [SKPhotoBroswer][1] for that one. It worked for me.

here is the code :

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let photos = self.detailsViewVM.getMoviePosterArray().map({
            SKPhoto.photoWithImageURL(
                AppHelper.getImageURL(usingURL: $0.poster)!.absoluteString
            )
        })
        let browser = SKPhotoBrowser(photos: photos)
        browser.initializePageIndex(indexPath.row)
        present(browser, animated: true, completion: {})
    }`

Before using SKPhotoBrowser : [Click here for image in collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GsoC.png)

After tapping on image: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLPpr.png)

Hope you will find this answer helpful.

Comment: I'm sure it's well-intentioned, but this is basically a link-only answer. You can improve it by expanding it to explain *how* SKPhotoBrowser solves the problem. However, it's far from clear that this answer really does address the OP's question.